# How to setUp the first or Initial ViewController after a splashscreen

Tags: swift3

I have this scenario:

1) When app starts, the app show the SplashScreen.

2) I need this splashScreen to run a simple logic

I am confused with the following:

```
Problem:

How to make SplashScreen with logic?
I add a new CocoaTouch file and call it SplashVC.swift 
and assign it to the UIViewController in the LaunchScreen.storyboard.

**at LaunchScreen.storyboard:**

I see there is an arrow on the left of the ViewController. 
This means it is the first VC to be loaded.

**at Main.storyboard**

I have a MainVC which I made it as the first Page to be loaded.

There are two VC which are the First Page to be loaded.
```

So, how do I do the the following tasks for LuanchScreen for the below :

conditions:
  if there is a value in UserDefaults, go to VC1
  if there is no value in UserDefaults, got to VC2

```
                          |- viewLogin
   SplashScreen.swift ----|
                          |- viewMain
```

**Update**
1) Delete the Default LaunchScreen called: LaunchScreen.storyboard

1.1 ) add interface file in the project

in file dialogBox:  select the user interface file of type : Launch Screen

name it : splash (it will create splash.storyboard)

2) Add a CocoaTouch File and Call it SplashVC.swift

3) Assign this SplashVC.swift to UIViewController in Splash.Storyboard

4) Click this UIViewController and goto File Inspector

at Interface Builder Document

untick :Use as LaunchScreen

5)  click the project and goto General

```
  Goto App Icons and Launch Images section <br/>
  Launch screen file : Splash.storyboard<br/>
```

6) I have the viewControllers I want to navigate to base on Condition in splashVC.swift:

viewLogin.swift
   viewMain.swift

7) Add code in SplashVC.swift

```
  func checkLogin()
        {
         var mainView: UIStoryboard!
        mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        var viewcontroller : UIViewController


             if UserDefaults.standard().bool(forKey: "login"){

viewcontroller = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewLogin") as! viewLogin

              }else {
                    viewcontroller = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewMain") as! viewMain
              }

//--- error : value of type SplashVC has no member 'window'


        self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible(); 
            }
        }
```

Error :

//--- error : value of type SplashVC has no member 'window'
              self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();

Please help. Thanks

Thanks

Comment: i have created separate splash vc where you can check your UserDefaults. and load view controller based on that condition.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple just remove the launch screen story board and add your own.

just follow the

> step:1 add your own storyboard with single view controller and assign
>   it to your own splashvc class.

[image]

> step:2 make your splash storyboard as main interface

[image]

now you can do any coding in splash like

```
 class SplashVC: UIViewController {

            override func viewDidLoad(){
                super.viewDidLoad();
                checkLogin()
            }
            override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
            {
                super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            }
        func checkLogin()
        {
         var mainView: UIStoryboard!
        mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        var viewcontroller : UIViewController;

             if   UserDefaults.standard().bool(forKey: "login"){
                  viewcontroller   = mainView.instantiateInitialViewController()!;
              }else {
                    viewcontroller   = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourSecondVcIde") as! YourSecondVC
              }
self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your splash.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard are the Same. Now, I have a MainVC.swift in Storyboard which is also the First Page to be loaded. Do I remove the arrow for MainVC? How to Load or navigate to VC1 or VC2 from func CheckLogin??

Comment: no i have removed LaunchScreen.storyboard because you cannot assign your class to launch screen

Comment: dont' remove arrow from main storyboard its separate one

Comment: How to navigate or load the VC1 or VC2 in your checkLogin func? can you show me. thanks.  Or How u naviagte to loginScreen or dashboardScreen?

Comment: will get back here after I try it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156623/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-milkbottle).